# jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/appcelerator/titanium/gen/bindings.json

Tags: javascript

I am facing issue while using custom module in titanium application:-

[ERROR] : Failed to sign apk:

[ERROR] : jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/appcelerator/titanium/gen/bindings.json

I have created new custom module for android and I am trying to use this module in my application but at run time I am getting above error.
I didn't get any solution yet please share if anyone have any idea related to this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Long discussion regarding this error on the Appc JIRA (https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23502)

From the PR (https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/pull/8551) looks like you will have to wait until 6.1.0 for the fix, or build a new sdk from master, or cherry pick the fixes into your current SDK.

In the discussion, Sean Conway offered a solution (https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23502?focusedCommentId=393172&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-393172) that worked for some folks, but not others.

> I was able to remove the gen/bindings.json file by doing the following:
>
> (1) Set Java Compiler to 1.8
>
> (2) Update build.properties:
>   titanium.platform=/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.4.0.GA/android
>   android.platform=/Users/xxx/Library/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-23
>   android.ndk=/Users/xxx/android-sdks/build-tools/22.0.1/android-ndk-r10e
>
> (3) Change all libraries in build path to use 5.4.0.GA JARS
>
> (4) Delete build and dist folders then rebuild using ANT *** WIll not work otherwise, still produces gen file if you package-->android module
>   DO not use package option to build, go to build.xml, right click-->Run as Ant Build
>
> Successful project build